# MySQL query to update ranking

Tags: mysql, rank

I have a mysql table with userid, rating and ranking as fields. The table is huge (>10K rows). I am trying to update ranking column of each row in a single query based on rating (higher rating is lower rank). If 2 or more users have same rating they have the same ranking but the next rank will skip that many users (if 2 users have rank 5, then next user will be rank 7).

I am trying to achieve this with the below query but don't know where I am going wrong.

```
UPDATE userprofile
            JOIN (SELECT p.userid,
                         IF(@last_rating<> p.rating,
                            @cur_rank := @cur_rank + @next_rank,
                            @cur_rank)  AS ranking,
                         IF(@last_rating= p.rating,
                            @next_rank := @next_rank + 1,
                            @next_rank := 1),
                         @last_rating:= p.rating
                    FROM userprofile p
                    JOIN (SELECT @cur_rank := 0, @last_rating:= -1, @next_rank := 1) r
                   ORDER BY  p.rating DESC
                  ) ranks ON (ranks.userid = userprofile.userid)
        SET userprofile.ranking = ranks.ranking
```

This is sample of the table before the query

```
+--------+--------+-----+------+------------+--------+--------------+---------+---------------+
| userid | played | won | lost |   streak   | rating | ratingchange | ranking | currentgameid |
+--------+--------+-----+------+------------+--------+--------------+---------+---------------+
|      1 |      1 |   0 |    0 | A          |      0 |            0 |       0 |             6 |
|      2 |      1 |   1 |    0 | W          |     50 |           50 |       0 |             2 |
|      7 |     13 |   4 |    5 | AWLLLWWLLW |    108 |           48 |       0 |             0 |
|      8 |      6 |   6 |    0 | WWWWWW     |    198 |           48 |       0 |             0 |
|      9 |      1 |   0 |    0 | A          |      0 |            0 |       0 |             0 |
|     10 |      1 |   1 |    0 | W          |     50 |           50 |       0 |             0 |
|     11 |      7 |   5 |    2 | WWWLWWL    |    142 |          -48 |       0 |             0 |
|     12 |      7 |   1 |    6 | LLLWLLL    |      0 |            0 |       0 |            26 |
|     13 |      5 |   3 |    1 | LWWAW      |     71 |           71 |       0 |             0 |
|     14 |      1 |   1 |    0 | W          |     71 |           71 |       0 |             0 |
|     15 |      0 |   0 |    0 |            |      0 |            0 |       0 |            26 |
+--------+--------+-----+------+------------+--------+--------------+---------+---------------+
```

And after the query

```
+--------+--------+-----+------+------------+--------+--------------+---------+---------------+
| userid | played | won | lost |   streak   | rating | ratingchange | ranking | currentgameid |
+--------+--------+-----+------+------------+--------+--------------+---------+---------------+
|      1 |      1 |   0 |    0 | A          |      0 |            0 |       1 |             6 |
|      2 |      1 |   1 |    0 | W          |     50 |           50 |       2 |             2 |
|      7 |     13 |   4 |    5 | AWLLLWWLLW |    108 |           48 |       3 |             0 |
|      8 |      6 |   6 |    0 | WWWWWW     |    198 |           48 |       4 |             0 |
|      9 |      1 |   0 |    0 | A          |      0 |            0 |       5 |             0 |
|     10 |      1 |   1 |    0 | W          |     50 |           50 |       6 |             0 |
|     11 |      7 |   5 |    2 | WWWLWWL    |    142 |          -48 |       7 |             0 |
|     12 |      7 |   1 |    6 | LLLWLLL    |      0 |            0 |       8 |            26 |
|     13 |      5 |   3 |    1 | LWWAW      |     71 |           71 |       9 |             0 |
|     14 |      1 |   1 |    0 | W          |     71 |           71 |       9 |             0 |
|     15 |      0 |   0 |    0 |            |      0 |            0 |      11 |            26 |
+--------+--------+-----+------+------------+--------+--------------+---------+---------------+
```

If I am using a select statement as below, it is giving me expected results in the ranks.ranking column but the SET statement is not working as expected.

```
SELECT userprofile.userid, userprofile.rating, ranks.userid, ranks.ranking FROM userprofile
            JOIN (SELECT p.userid,
                         IF(@last_rating<> p.rating,
                            @cur_rank := @cur_rank + @next_rank,
                            @cur_rank)  AS ranking,
                         IF(@last_rating= p.rating,
                            @next_rank := @next_rank + 1,
                            @next_rank := 1),
                         @last_rating:= p.rating
                    FROM userprofile p
                    JOIN (SELECT @cur_rank := 0, @last_rating:= -1, @next_rank := 1) r
                   ORDER BY  p.rating DESC
                  ) ranks ON (ranks.userid = userprofile.userid)
```

Result of the Select Query

```
+--------+--------+--------+---------+
| userid | rating | userid | ranking |
+--------+--------+--------+---------+
|      8 |    198 |      8 |       1 |
|     11 |    142 |     11 |       2 |
|      7 |    108 |      7 |       3 |
|     13 |     71 |     13 |       4 |
|     14 |     71 |     14 |       4 |
|      2 |     50 |      2 |       6 |
|     10 |     50 |     10 |       6 |
|      1 |      0 |      1 |       8 |
|      9 |      0 |      9 |       8 |
|     12 |      0 |     12 |       8 |
|     15 |      0 |     15 |       8 |
+--------+--------+--------+---------+
```

Comment: Pls describe exactly what went wrong, do not ask us to figure that out as well!

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Finding it hard to copy my table data as text here. Can you suggest any software which can convert text separated by a character to text that can be pasted here?

Comment: https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/

Comment: Sorry bro, I give up. It is an uphill task to try convert those mysql tables as readable text and put it here

Comment: Can you copy/paste to excel? Excel to that website work very easy.

Comment: Thanks man, didnt figure out that I had to format it as code for it to properly align. Updated all images with text now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you create a temporal table, and then perform the update?

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/TGRK98598)**

```
CREATE TABLE test as 
SELECT userprofile.*, ranks.ranking  as newRank
FROM userprofile
JOIN (SELECT p.userid,
             IF(@last_rating<> p.rating,
                @cur_rank := @cur_rank + @next_rank,
                @cur_rank)  AS ranking,
             IF(@last_rating= p.rating,
                @next_rank := @next_rank + 1,
                @next_rank := 1),
             @last_rating:= p.rating
      FROM userprofile p
      JOIN (SELECT @cur_rank := 0, @last_rating:= -1, @next_rank := 1) r
      ORDER BY  p.rating DESC
    ) ranks 
ON (ranks.userid = userprofile.userid);
```

Update

```
UPDATE userprofile
JOIN test
  ON userprofile.`userid`  = test.`userid`
SET userprofile.ranking = test.newRank;
```

Comment: I have modified the SQL as given below in the answer. Any reason why UPDATE and creating the rankings were not working in the same query?

Comment: There is a line in the [**manual**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) `However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined.` I'm trying to see if there is a way to force the order. But meanwhile this is the easy way so you can move on your problem.

Comment: For your reference, [**this**](http://rextester.com/LHG14184) is how I would do it. But still same problem. Looks like try to use the original table order.  That is why the `10` is number `, if the data is on the correct order the update works ok.

Answer (score 0):

This is the query that finally worked for me.
Choosing Juan's answer as the accepted answer, as it was the answer which suggested to do it like this.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;

CREATE TABLE t1 AS
SELECT userprofile.userid, ranks.ranking FROM userprofile
            JOIN (SELECT p.userid,
                         IF(@last_rating<> p.rating,
                            @cur_rank := @cur_rank + @next_rank,
                            @cur_rank)  AS ranking,
                         IF(@last_rating= p.rating,
                            @next_rank := @next_rank + 1,
                            @next_rank := 1),
                         @last_rating:= p.rating
                    FROM userprofile p
                    JOIN (SELECT @cur_rank := 0, @last_rating:= -1, @next_rank := 1) r
                   ORDER BY  p.rating DESC
                  ) ranks ON (ranks.userid = userprofile.userid);

UPDATE userprofile JOIN t1 ON userprofile.userid = t1.userid
SET userprofile.ranking = t1.ranking;

DROP TABLE t1;
```

Comment: just in case, you should start with `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;`

Comment: Noted, thanks a lot for the help. Updated in the answer